# Tox throws an error when running sphinx-build through Poetry in Docker container

Tags: python-sphinx, tox, python-poetry

I am trying to generate Sphinx documentation for a project using Poetry and Tox. I have this configuration:

```
# tox.ini
[tox]
envlist = py36
isolated_build = True

[tox:.package]
basepython = python3

[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands =
    poetry install -v
    poetry run pytest tests/

[testenv:docs]
description = invoke sphinx-build to build the HTML docs
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands = poetry run sphinx-build -d "{toxworkdir}/docs_doctree" documentation/source "{toxworkdir}/docs_out" --color -bhtml {posargs}
           python -c 'import pathlib; print("documentation available under file://\{0\}".format(pathlib.Path(r"{toxworkdir}") / "docs_out" / "index.html"))'
```

```
# pyproject.toml
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "My project"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
apache-beam = {extras = ["gcp"], version = "^2.24.0"}
click = "^7.1"
click-log = "^0.3"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^6.1"
black = "20.8b1"
sphinx = "^3.2.1"
sphinx-autoapi = "^1.5"
```

Locally, I can run the following command lines to generate the documentation, they all work:

- `cd documentation; make html`
- `tox -e docs`

But for CI in Bamboo, I chose to run in a Docker container (FROM python:3.6 with Poetry and Tox installed) to avoid issues with other packages installed on the agent, and then `tox -e docs` throws an error:

```
 docs run-test: commands[0] | poetry run sphinx-build -d /app/.tox/docs_doctree documentation/source /app/.tox/docs_out --color -bhtml

  FileNotFoundError

  [Errno 2] No such file or directory
 
   at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/os.py:594 in _execvpe
        590│         path_list = map(fsencode, path_list)
        591│     for dir in path_list:
        592│         fullname = path.join(dir, file)
        593│         try:
     →  594│             exec_func(fullname, *argrest)
        595│         except OSError as e:
        596│             last_exc = e
        597│             tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        598│             if (e.errno != errno.ENOENT and e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR
 ERROR: InvocationError for command /usr/local/bin/poetry run sphinx-build -d .tox/docs_doctree documentation/source .tox/docs_out --color -bhtml (exited > with code 1)
```

If I run a `docker exec` to get an interactive shell in the container and run `/usr/local/bin/poetry run sphinx-build -d .tox/docs_doctree documentation/source .tox/docs_out --color -bhtml`, the documentation is generated.

I can't find the reason for this error. I found a workaround by putting sphinx dependencies directly in Tox configuration, but I now have dependencies in both files and I'd like to understand what happened:

```
deps =
    sphinx == 3.2.1
    sphinx-autoapi == 1.5.1
commands = poetry run sphinx-build -d "{toxworkdir}/docs_doctree" documentation/source "{toxworkdir}/docs_out" --color -bhtml {posargs}
           python -c 'import pathlib; print("documentation available under file://\{0\}".format(pathlib.Path(r"{toxworkdir}") / "docs_out" / "index.html"))'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look, I would say:

The `commands` setting in `[testenv:docs]` overwrites the one from `[testenv]`. So I guess it is assumed that `poetry install -v` has been ran in the `docs` test environment but it has not. Anyway `sphinx` (and other dependencies) are not installed in the `docs` test environment.

You might want to add some variant of `poetry install` at the top of the `commands` setting in `[testenv:docs]`.

Comment: You were right, I've added `poetry install` before `poetry run sphinx-build` and it worked. I'm just beginning to use Tox and I assumed there was something specific with Docker and didn't think about dependencies installation. Thank you